# CSS width in % and height in px and both same length

Tags: javascript, css, html

What I try to make is square that change size with the size of the screen.

So I have the width set to 25%.
How do I make sure that the height keeps the same length in px as the width?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of so many questions, try searching harder next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use top/bottom `padding` property in percentage, to achieve the result.

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/jodevaga/37/edit)**.

```css
.box {
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
}
```

A [percentage value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434053/position-absolute-top-property-based-on-the-parent-width/21434501#21434501) on top/bottom `padding` or `margins` is relative to the width of the box's containing block.

> **[8.4 Padding properties: 'padding-top', 'padding-right', 'padding-bottom', 'padding-left', and 'padding'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties)**
>
> `<percentage>`
>    The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of
>   the generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and
>   'padding-bottom'.

---

### Adding the content

Since the the height of the box grows by adding content, we could wrap the content by an element `.wrapper` and position that absolutely relative to the box, and then use `top`, `right`, `left` and `bottom` properties to fill the entire space of the box.

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/qatuyuye/45/edit)**

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- content goes here... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.box {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%; /*  1:1 square */
}

.box > .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

---

For further information you could refer [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474) *(Responsive Container section)*.

Comment: works here http://jsfiddle.net/u2Qbk/

Comment: No idea why that was down-voted, that's the solution I would use, and the square re-sizes nicely.

Comment: It works until content is added..http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/u2Qbk/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D I've explained how to add the content in the posted link.

Comment: @Paulie_D You're right, here's an updated example of your code to fix the content issue http://jsfiddle.net/trzFs/

Comment: @Paulie_D Updated the answer to fix the content issue.

Answer (score 0):

you may set the width value as a percentage, then grab it with jquery then let it to be the height value. see this

```
var box = $(".box");
var width = box.css("width");
box.css("height", width);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DPYcg/1/

Answer (score 0):

To be able to add contents, you may use pseudo element and floats behavior : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fklAr/

```
div {
  width:25%;
  background:red;
  margin:auto;
}
div:before, div:after {
  content:'';
}
div:before {
  float:left;
  padding-top:100%;
}
div:after {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

maybe a duplicate if you want to center content : [Center content in the middle of div container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179712/center-content-in-the-middle-of-div-container/22179999#22179999)